# How to display ipywidgets.Dropdown without a value selected

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

No question anymore. The problem is older ipywidgets version behaviour that looks to be fixed in version 7.

The ipywidgets.Dropdown on its own picks up the first value out of the options list.
I would like to display the widget without a value selected.
The first value in the list is a pointless default that still needs to be reflected down the workflow path. I read a discussion where a developer went as far as adding empty string item into the list. That fixes the dropdown look (to some extent though as the placeholder attribute is still ignored) but adds a silly selectable empty item to the dropdown list. Adding dummy "None" item to the list is not much better solution.Setting value to None results in the "Invalid selection" exception.
I do not understand why the ipywidgets.Dropdown does not follow approach of the simpler widgets where empty value is allowed and placeholder text is dispalyed to prompt the user to select something.
Is there a way to make the widget selection not required? Some attribute setting I am not aware of? If that is impossible then what is the simplest possible workaround?

Answer (score 8):

You can just set the dropdown value to `None`:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

d = widgets.Dropdown(options=['hello', 'world'], value=None)
d
```

[image: Dropdown widget]

Comment: Yes, I was able to set None as value but only after upgrading my ipywidgets to 7.0.0 from  6.0.1. Surprised much to see such basic behaviour fixed only in so high version number.

Answer (score 0):

in 'ipywidgets' version 7.2.1 you will need to disable user changes to be able to display the widget by setting it to False like this:

```
d = widgets.Dropdown(options=['hello', 'world'], value=None, disabled=False)
```